# String search keep returning empty in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have kept trying to get my code to work but I keep getting blank output and I am not allowed to import anything e.g. RE:

```
choc1 ='         outf.write("/# " + str(number) + " #/ " + line) #lots of cake(#) lovers here'

EC = choc1
ECout = EC
out = ""
for x in ECout :
      if x!="#[a-z,A-Z]":
            x = x.replace(x,"")
            out += x
if out== '#lots of cake(#) lovers here':
      print("well done Lucy")
else:
      print(out)
```

I must be really stupid as this should be simple - I need to return '#lots of cake(#) lovers here' but I'm stuck on this assignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance - Jemma

Comment: Take a look at [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (regular expressions) and its function [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: unfortunately i'm not allowed to import any functionality e.g. re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your for loop, you are examining each character in a string individually, and comparing this to a string that is several characters long. Is this what you intended? Consider:

```
>>> a = "abc"
>>> for x in a:
...   print(x)
... 
a
b
c
```

Perhaps you meant to take each character, and compare that character to each character separately in the other string with a slightly different statement?